# Java statistics by words in long string

Tags: java, string, optimization, words

I'm writing a program in java to get statistics on words in a very big string(string s <= 100000). This should take less then 1 second and use less than 16 MB of memory.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){


  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String t = sc.nextLine();
  int i=0;
  while(t.charAt(i)==' ') i++;
  t = t.substring(i);
  String[] s = t.split(" +");

  RecString[] stat  = new RecString[s.length];
  for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){
    stat[i] = new RecString("");  
  }
  int j=0;
  for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){
    int f=0;
    for(int h =0; h<stat.length; h++){
     if(stat[h].word.equals(s[i])){
       f = 1;
       stat[h].count++;
       break;
     }
    }
    if(f==0){
      stat[j] = new RecString(s[i]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<=j;i++){
   if(stat[i].word != ""){
      System.out.println(stat[i].word+" "+(stat[i].count));
   }
  }


 }
}

class RecString{
    public  String word;
    public  int count;

    public RecString(String s){
        word = s;
        count = 1;
    }

}
```

This code works on strings with the length <=255
But for big strings I have time or/and memory limit.

Help me please to optimize my program

Comment: Are you counting the number of occurrences of each word?! Or...?

Comment: The amount of memory used for such a trivial application will probably largely be based on what your heap size and JVM are set to. Also reading by newline is always asking for a potential memory issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes, i counting the number of occurrences of each word.

Comment: I don't really understand the code; not sure why there isn't just a map of words => counts--should be trivial. What do you mean by "use less than 16M of memory"? The whole thing, including the JVM?

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes, i counting the number of occurrences of each word.    i get array by string after use .split and create new array by records (word and count). for all elements of this record i set word = "" and count = 0. then i passers- by elements of array s, if this element there is in stat i increment count of this word, else I add new word in stat

Comment: @user2279756 So, why not use a map of words => count? A naive implementation should be maybe a dozen lines of code, not whatever that is you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concerned with memory you will want to try to stream as much as possible.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while(tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){

    if(tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
        // found a word.
        System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
    }
}
```

Of course if memory was not a problem and speed was your only concern Hadoop has an excellent word counting example: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount . But save that for a rainy day of learning.

Also your logic of counting words is not right for efficiency (its `O(N)`). @DaveNewton is right that you probably should use a `Map<String,Integer>` which will give you `O(1)` and not your array of `RecString`. I'm not going to correct your conde on that as I think its a good exercise.